# Is it possible to get a list of names from sharepoint by first letter using CamlQuery?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

i am new to SharePoint. I have this query:

```
 getAttendanceQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='TypeEvent'/><Value Type='Text'>" + selectedChoice["TypeEvent"].ToString() + 
          "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + xDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>";
```

I need to add a condition to query the first letter of the last name; so I can get a smaller list back. Is it possible? and how?

I changed the query to this and it did not work. Am I doing anything wrong? (I added *x0020* in the filed name because i have a space in sharepoint)

```
"<View><Query><Where>" + 
     "<And>" +
         "<Eq>" + 
             "<FieldRef Name='TypeEvent'/>" +
             "<Value Type='Text'>" + selectedChoice["TypeEvent"].ToString() + "</Value>" + 
        "</Eq>" + 
        "<And>" + 
            "<Eq>" + 
                "<FieldRef Name='Date' />" + 
                "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + xDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "</Value>" + 
            "</Eq>" + 
            "<BeginsWith>" + 
                "<FieldRef Name='Last_x0020_Name' />" +
                "<Value Type='Text'>"+ fletter +"</Value>" +
            "</BeginsWith>" +
        "</And>" + 
    "</And>" +
"</Where></Query></View>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to query a "user or group" field, then no, there is no method by which to sort or filter based on surname only.

If, on the other hand, you have the last name in a separate text field, you can use the `<BeginsWith>` element in your CAML query.

Your final CAML query might look like this:

```
"<View><Query><Where>" + 
     "<And>" +
         "<Eq>" + 
             "<FieldRef Name='TypeEvent'/>" +
             "<Value Type='Text'>" + selectedChoice["TypeEvent"].ToString() + "</Value>" + 
        "</Eq>" + 
        "<And>" + 
            "<Eq>" + 
                "<FieldRef Name='Date' />" + 
                "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + xDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "</Value>" + 
            "</Eq>" + 
            "<BeginsWith>" + 
                "<FieldRef Name='LastNameField' />" +
                "<Value Type='Text'>"+ desiredLetter +"</Value>" +
            "</BeginsWith>" +
        "</And>" + 
    "</And>" +
"</Where></Query></View>";
```

(Replacing `LastNameField` and `desiredLetter` with the appropriate column name and variable name as necessary.)